# Digital Music Player (SD to USB)

Tags: usb, sd-card

I own a couple of digital in-ear headphones that connect to my phone using USB (some micro, some type C), i.e. they have a built-in DAC and amp. Now instead of having to carry my phone along to listen to music, I'd like to build a portable music player - think of it as an iPod Shuffle minus the DAC+AMP - and I think the Arduino platform should be well-suited for a first prototype(?).

So if I understand correctly, then all I need is the following:

- an Arduino board
- some storage (i.e. a micro-SD card module)
- a serial to USB-C module
- some code that streams the files to serial

then "optionally":

- a battery
- some controls

Am I on the right track?
The headphones connect as USB OTG slave devices, so the Arduino will need to be the master - is that an issue? Also, is it possible to output serial data through the Arduino's own USB port? I've looked around, but my findings are somewhat inconclusive. On the other hand, this might not matter since I will need to power it somehow anyway...

As you may have guessed, this is my first Arduino project, so please be kind ^.^

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to research more about how USB Type-C Audio works, because it most certainly isn't the most standard serial connection people use with Arduinos. One is for sure, you'd have to use either an expensive shield or an 32bit (fast) Arduino to even have USB.

Comment: Errrr... no.  Just no.  For a first Arduino project do something else. This will not be possible for you. It won't even be possible for me using an Arduino and I am (as some people say) a demigod.

Comment: Haha, alright, only a fool wouldn't trust the word of a demigod. I guess sometimes things aren't quite as simple as they may appear - it's simple to drive an actual speaker, andI assumed taking away the dac shouldn't make things harder. But I guess USB comes with its own set of challenges...thanks for the feedback!